# App crashes on Emulator, but works on physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

I have an app that I can run on a physical ZTE Majesty Pro and it works fine, and I can run it on an AVD tablet. When I tried it on a Pixel AVD and a Nexus 5X AVD, the  app crashes on startup. I don't know why this is happening, does it have something to do with the screen size? This is the layout that I believe may be affecting it. I use a lot of images for the layout, so do I need to scale down my images to make it run? If that is the case, how could I scale them down? Logcat doesn't log any data when I run it on the Pixel or Nexus either.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/bottom_nav">
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/new_spotting"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:contentDescription="@string/spotting"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="#44ba52"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/map_background"
    android:background="@drawable/curvelines"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/HomeButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/home"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/homebutton" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/MapButton"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/map"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/mapbutton" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/MenuButton"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menubutton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/new_spotting_page"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add a New Sighting"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type of Animal:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/moose_select"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:onClick="onClick">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/moose"
                android:id="@+id/moose"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Moose"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/moose"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/moose"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/moose"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/moose"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/bear_select"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:onClick="onClick">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/bear"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bear"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bear"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bear"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bear"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bear"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bear"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/deer_select"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:onClick="onClick">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/deer"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/deer"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Deer"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/deer"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/deer"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/deer"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/deer"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/coyote_select"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:onClick="onClick">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/coyote"
                android:id="@+id/coyote"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Coyote"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/coyote"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/coyote"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/coyote"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/coyote"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/lion_select"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:onClick="onClick">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/lion"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lion"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Puma"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lion"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lion"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lion"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lion"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/fox_select"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:onClick="onClick">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/fox"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fox"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fox"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fox"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fox"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fox"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fox"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/add"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spacer"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spacer"
            android:text="Add to Map"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: no one is gonna answer your question till you point out issue, add code and add error logs

Comment: check android studio logcat, edit your question & paste logcat error part

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the error log from **Logcat**.

Are you implementing and using any Google Service? If yes check if your Virtual Device has the Google API.